# integer comparison not working correctly in EL (JSP)

Tags: jsp, el

I have the following code in my jsp -

```
 c:if test="${serviceOutput.ok}">
        <c:if test="${serviceOutput.ret.proposalsCount} > 0">
......
```

and printing ${serviceOutput.ret.proposalsCount} gives the following -

```
${serviceOutput.ret.proposalsCount}
--> 3
```

Which clearly means that proposalsCount value is 3 which is more than 0, but still in my original jsp, this conditional evaluates out to false.

Can anyone please help me out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *entire* [EL expression](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) needs to go inside the brackets `{}`.

```
<c:if test="${serviceOutput.ret.proposalsCount > 0}">
```